# Hotkey to toggle checkboxes does opposite

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PZyN/), I have a table with checkboxes in the first column.  The master checkbox in the table header functions as expected toggling the state of all the checkboxes in the table when it is clicked.

I have set up a hotkey for <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to toggle the master checkbox.  The desired behavior when using the hotkey is:

1. The master checkbox is toggled
2. The child checkboxes each have their checked state set to match the master

But what is actually happening is the opposite...

1. The child checkboxes each have their checked state set to match the master
2. The master checkbox is toggled

Here is the relevant code

```
$(".master-select").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("table").find("tbody .row-select").prop('checked', this.checked);
});

function tickAllCheckboxes() {
  var master = $(".master-select").click();
}

//using jquery.hotkeys.js to assign hotkey
$(document).bind('keydown', 'shift+x', tickAllCheckboxes);
```

This results in the child checkboxes having the opposite checked state of the master checkbox. Why is that happening?  A fix would be nice, but I'm really after an explanation so I can understand what is happening.

Comment: passing `'shift+x'` as a parameter to `bind` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: I'm using the jquery.hotkeys.js plugin for jQuery which makes that work. Edited code to make that clear.

Comment: ah, not familiar with that plugin. good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".master-select").click(function(){
    var checked = true;
    if(this.checked){
        checked = false;
    }
    $(this).closest("table").find("tbody .row-select").prop('checked', checked);
});
```

The problem is that you are not actually `clicking the checkbox` , but `triggering it`.
SO the state of the checkbox will be in the **previous state** wherever you trigger it..

You need to handle the logic for the **trigger and the manual click explicitly**..

Try this code

```
$(".master-select").click(function(e) {
    var checked;
    if (e.isTrigger) { // Logic when click is triggered
        checked = true;
        if (this.checked) {
            checked = false;
        }
    }
    else {  // Explicit click 
       checked = this.checked;
    }

    $(this).closest("table").find("tbody .row-select").prop('checked', checked);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/4PZyN/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I would like to know why triggering a click behaves differently than a click.

Comment: That is because you are triggering the click but not setting it's current property to checked/unchecked..  When click it is taken care of automatically

Comment: Because when the current state of the checkbox is `unchecked`.. Then you hit `shift-x` , the state of it still `unchecked` as it state will not chage immediately after being triggered.... It will change after  event is completed .. But when manually clicked it's state will be immediately reflected upon